# What are "collective conventions"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, legalese

> Conventions and recommendations adopted by the International Labour Organization **in the area of collective conventions**, prohibition of forced labour and child labour, defence of the rights of indigenous peoples, and equal treatment and non-discrimination in the work place;
>   [Source](http://dtxtq4w60xqpw.cloudfront.net/sites/all/files/docpdf/gcetbrochureglobalcodeen.pdf)

Unfortunately I can not find the definition of "collective conventions". I know it is a special term. ِDO they have the same meaning of "collective agreements"? What does this exactly mean?

Comment: See also: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/collective-bargaining. I believe that this "collective conventions" means "collective bargaining conventions" as shown in lots of search results on ILO.

Comment: From [a document on International Labour Organization's website](http://www.ilo.org/global/topics/collective-bargaining-labour-relations/WCMS_309858/lang--fr/index.htm): *Le dialogue social, y compris la négociation collective et l’application des conventions
collectives, peut s’inscrire dans le cadre de l’infrastructure visant à protéger l’indépendance et l’impartialité de la fonction publique. Il doit avoir, entre autres objectifs, celui de créer des conditions transparentes qui puissent permettre à la fonction publique de développer une culture éthique capable d’empêcher la corruption.*

Comment: Its English translation: *"Social dialogue, including collective bargaining and the implementation of collective agreements, can be part of the infrastructure that protects the independence and impartiality of the public service. Social dialogue should aim at, among other things, creating transparent conditions in which the public service develops an ethical culture that prevents corruption."*

Comment: @DamkerngT. information-rich! Why not write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: I believe that the ***collective conventions*** in this context refers to conventions of ***[collective bargaining](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/collective-bargaining)*** (discussions between employers and labor unions about pay and working conditions) as adopted by the International Labour Organization.

---

Here is my long answer. Let's discuss our context a bit. Your source document is *GLOBAL CODE OF ETHICS FOR TOURISM* and the text you quoted is an instrument (a formal document) listed under this section "Referring in particular to the following instruments:" (page 3). Here is the text of the item in the bullet list:

> Conventions and recommendations adopted by the International Labour
>   Organization in the area of collective conventions, prohibition of forced
>   labour and child labour, defence of the rights of indigenous peoples, and
>   equal treatment and non-discrimination in the work place;

What does that mean?

It means the Code of Ethics refers to "conventions" and "recommendations", which I believe are also formal documents. These conventions and recommendations are adopted by the International Labour Organization. The Code of Ethics specifically refers to these conventions and recommendations in particular "area", which includes: collective conventions, prohibition of forced
labour and child labour, defence of the rights of indigenous peoples, and
equal treatment and non-discrimination in the work place.

*Collective* and *convention* can be found in dictionaries. Roughly, "collective conventions" should mean something along the lines "conventions that are involving all the members of a group". This looks a bit ambiguous to me. Some clues we have are that these conventions are in the context of ILO, and are about labour, rights, and work place.

After a few searches on [ILO's website](http://www.ilo.org/), it's rather clear that this "collective conventions" should refer to "collective bargaining conventions" as I mentioned in my short answer above.

The first search result of `collective convention` that has the two words next to each other is this document (in French): [GDFPS/2014/11 *Rapport final de la discussion Forum de dialogue mondial sur les défis à relever en matière de négociation collective
dans la fonction publique* (Genève, 2-3 avril 2014)](http://www.ilo.org/global/topics/collective-bargaining-labour-relations/WCMS_309858/lang--fr/index.htm). Here is the part relevant to the search:

> *Le dialogue social, y compris la négociation collective et l’application des conventions collectives, peut s’inscrire dans le cadre de l’infrastructure visant à protéger l’indépendance et l’impartialité de la fonction publique. Il doit avoir, entre autres objectifs, celui de créer des conditions transparentes qui puissent permettre à la fonction publique de développer une culture éthique capable d’empêcher la corruption.*

And here is its translation in English:

> Social dialogue, including collective bargaining and the implementation of collective agreements, can be part of the infrastructure that protects the independence and impartiality of the public service. Social dialogue should aim at, among other things, creating transparent conditions in which the public service develops an ethical culture that prevents corruption.

Comment: Your French version adds a phrase  that clarifies things:  *la négociation collective*.  Your reading is certainly plausible, but the original quote says nothing about "bargaining".

Answer (score 1):

*Collective conventions* refers to the rules agreed upon by *all members of the organization* with respect to those practices.

Comment: Could you give me a link explaining this?

Comment: Does it say there should be rules in organization which have been agreed on by all parties through discussion?

Comment: If you consult a good dictionary, you'll find the relevant definitions of *collective* and *convention*.  In the quotation, there is nothing about what "should be". BTW, you should provide the entire sentence and a link. As it stands, it's only a sentence fragment.

Comment: thx. I edited. the Source is now right in the box

Comment: With respect to the question of "should there be rules":  the quotation is a bullet-point (only a sentence-fragment) in the section of the document that begins: "**Referring** in particular to the following instruments:". The conventions and recommendations are among the "instruments" (i.e. legal documents having some sway or efficacy in a particular domain of activity or behavior).

Comment: Yes, then what does *Conventions and recommendations adopted by the International Labour Organization in the area of collective conventions* mean?

Comment: Have you looked up the word "convention"? Have you heard of the Geneva Conventions, for example?

Comment: Yes I have. I think the convention in *Geneva Convention* is something different to *collective conventions*

Comment: @Juya: of course they are different conventions, but what is it about the word *conventions* or the word *collective* that you don't understand?? You are not making very clear the nature of the trouble you're having.

Comment: Reading your and Damkerng T.'s replies I now understand them better.